# Dart get the middle strings of every specific character

Tags: flutter, dart, split

I need to get strings of every "|" character.

`String type = "123|234|24";`

The output should be a list of strings.

`List<String> subtypes = ["123","234","24"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Split** method as following.

```
 String type = "123|234|24";
  List<String> list = type.split('|').toList();
  print(list);
```

Comment: @ChethanaArunodh accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `split` method on the `String`. Check the code below, it works well:

```
   String type = "123|234|24";
   // split the string using a pattern(|)
   final subtypes = type.split('|');
   // print the values
   print(subtypes);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[123, 234, 24]
```

Note: You don't need to convert the subtypes to a list because `Dart` explicitly converts the result when the `split` method is used to a `List`